# is there a way in Nuxt 3 to access data stored in localStorage before reaching the client?

Tags: vuejs3, local-storage, nuxtjs3

In my app the user can choose the display language, and I add it to all ongoing requests to my Laravel backend so that the response comes depending on the language.

when I was using pure Vuejs, it was easy to store the "language" in localStorage and use it whenever needed. but for Nuxt I have to send some GET requests on the server where I don't have access to localStorage. and that's my problem.

it would be great if there was some Nuxt composable or some trick I don't know about that allows me to access data in LocalStorage on the server.

I found a "useCookie" composable, but it tourned out if it didn't have a "maxAge" or "expires" it will get removed as soon as the client closes his browser, and that's not what I need.

Regards!